# SQL Server - remove left part of string before a specific character

Tags: sql-server

I have a VARCHAR value that looks like this:

```
5.95 $ Additional fees
```

How can I remove everything left from character '$' (including that character) ? So that I get the following result:

```
Additional fees
```

The '$' is always present.

Answer (score 4):

`STUFF` and `CHARINDEX` would be the simpliest way, in my opinion:

```
SELECT STUFF(YourColumn,1, CHARINDEX('$',YourColumn),'')
FROM (VALUES('5.95 $ Additional fees'))V(YourColumn);
```

Note that as `$` has a whitespace afterwards, the value returned will have a leading whitespace (`' Additional fees'`). You could use `TRIM` (or `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` on older versions of SQL Server) to remove this, if it isn't wanted.

I haven't assumed that the portion string to be replaced is `CHARINDEX('$',YourColumn)+1`, as we have one sample. As far as we know, you could also have values such as `'10.99$Base Cost'`. If the `+1` was used, it would return `'ase Cost'` for such a value.

Answer (score 3):

Hello do it like below syntax
[image]

```
declare @temp nvarchar(max)='5.95 $ Additional fees'
select SUBSTRING(@temp,charindex('$',@temp)+1,len(@temp)-1)
```

Comment: If you want to remove while space at starting and ending, 

select ltrim( rtrim(SUBSTRING(@temp,charindex('$',@temp)+1,len(@temp)-1)))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTRING` get the particular string and `CHARINDEX` function to get index of special character, in your case `$`.

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(100)

SET @Var = '5.95 $ Additional fees'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Var, CHARINDEX('$', @Var) + 1, LEN(@Var) - LEN(LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX('$', @Var))))
```

Comment: I'd be reluctant to assume that 100 characters would be enough to satisfy the requirement.  Why not use a length function to calculate how many characters to take instead?

Comment: @Martin, Yes we can calculate `LEN`...edited the answer.